# regex match string of exactly 6 numbers in text that has telephone numbers as well

Tags: php, regex

I have blocks of free text that contain phone numbers and multiple 6 digit numbers that I need to capture. The 6 digit number has an optional ','.

examples of the 6 digit numbers could be 123456, or 123,456, but I need to differentiate from a phone number like 1 234 456 8901

I have :

```
    preg_match_all(",\[\W_][0-9]{3}(?:,)[0-9]{3}[\W_][\D]\d",$html, $value);
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Careful asking regex questions on stackoverflow. Automatic downvoting by the regex trolls. I see someone already gave you a downvote. But your question is completely valid.

Comment: better? is there a problem with what you have?

Comment: Can you give an example of a "multiple 6-digit number"? Or what the format is for a phone number in your locale?

Comment: Provide some samples of valid inputs and your expected matched output.

Comment: Caraful asking poorly specified questions on StackOverflow or you could be getting close votes from the "unclear what you are asking" bigots.

Comment: Sorry, I've tried to make it clearer with some examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to review the regex without the sample input but couple of observations:

- `[0-9]` can be replaced with `\d` (since, you're already using it at the end)
- `[\D]` is exactly the same as `\D`. It's a character class itself and unless you have some more characters to include it'ss fine without being enclosed in `[]`.
- `(?:,)` should simply be `,` because you neither want to capture it nor it has any *quantifiers*.
- `,\[\W_]` Here it seems you want to use the character class but the `\` would escape the first `[`. If you actually need a literal `\` there; you need to escape it as `\\` since it's a special character.